# samsung smart tv emulator does not appear?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I have downloaded the latest sdk, unzipped to desktop and tried to run my first helloworld app but nothing happened on eclipse. There is no any building, there is no any process at the moment, there is no any error, etc. When I click to "Run Samsung Smart Tv Emulator" nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to download "SDK Emulator Image for Virtual Box" and install VirtualBox

[Install Procedure (Samsung Developer Forum)](http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/d11/index.html#install-procedure)

[VirtualBox Downloads](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)